# Install SwiftKey on iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode-simulator, swiftkey

Is it possible to install SwiftKey on iPhone simulator ? If yes, how may I ? There are few scenarios I want to test for Swift keyboard but I am out of device.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, no. You can't install appstore apps on the simulator, your best shot would be to talk with SwiftKey and see if they give you access to the source code, this way you could compile it to the simulator and activate the keyboard, but I really doubt they would do that.